# PHP Regexp header (session id)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the following code :

```
$html = get_data($url);
```

I want to extract a session ID from this code, which has the following form :

> PHPSESSID=aaabbb123456789;

I'd like to store the session id (only the ID) in a var. I use this regexp :

```
preg_match('#PHPSESSID=(.+?);#is', $html, $result);
```

I almost get what I want, but the $result tab contains two strings. Here is the `var_dump()`:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(37) "PHPSESSID=aaabbb123456789;" [1]=> string(26) "aaabbb123456789" }
```

I would like `preg_match()` to return only the ID, as in `$result[1]`. What should I change in the regexp ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result list of regex matches often has the first result being the entire string. PHP's [`preg_match()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) guarantees this as well:

> If **matches** is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. `$matches[0]` will contain the text that matched the full pattern, `$matches[1]` will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

So you can safely just extract the value as `$result[1]` without worrying that it might change and cause a warning.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change that, it's how that command works.

$result[0] will always be the whole matched regex, while every index after that will correspond to a group.

You could eliminate the subsequent indices by not using a group, like this:

```
preg_match('#(?<=PHPSESSID=)[^;]+#i', $html, $result);
```

Now the session id will always be in $result[0]

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "aaabbb123456789" }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not exactly answers your question, but when it comes to string handling and parsing, I usually prefer not to use regex when it's not necessary

```
str_replace("PHPSESSID=", "", str_replace(";", "", $yourString));
```

unless your string contains more than "PHPSESSID=aaabbb123456789;"